# Passbook push notifications with deep link to Safari (or any web browser)

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-watch, deep-linking, passbook

After contacting apple support, it appears that passbook push notifications can only deep link to native iOS apps, not to a browser. I'm looking to deep link to an actual URL that opens in safari (the actual browser is irrelevant).

Scenario: user received a push notification through passbook. User taps on notification. Notification deepkingks to a browser web URL

Has somebody found a work around? Thanks!

Comment: How are you currently deep linking to other applications?

Comment: In this scenario (passbook notifications) I'm not linking to other apps and for now I just want to be able to launch a web address on a browser (Safari or Chrome)

Comment: @PassKit I am also curious if this is possible?